# Why won't v-model of a subcomponent reflow from an emit changed to the parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a numerical text input for my VueJS application that will allow math.js expressions to be evaluated in the text field. The idea is that on blur or on pressing enter inside the text box, the expression will be evaluated, if possible.

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="localValue"
    @blur="onBlur"
    @keydown="onKeydown"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { create, all } from 'mathjs'
const math = create(all)

export default {
    name: "NumericTextField",
    props: ["value"],
    data () {
        return {
            localValue: this.value
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onKeydown (e) {
            if (e.key === "Enter") {
                this.compute()
            }
        },
        onBlur () {
            this.compute()
        },
        compute () {
            try {
                const result = math.evaluate(this.localValue)
                this.$emit("input", result)
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

I seeing that data propagated out through the emit statement. However, the new value, once computed, is not reflowing into the v-model of the text field. I have tried a console.log on my data function and I am actually seeing the new this.value after an emit is done. So if I type 1+1 in the field and press enter, I will see console.log of the emit show 2, and also data recomputed shows this.value is now 2. However, the visual output is that v-text-field's data does not change, and 1+1 is still displayed in the text box. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

Option 1 - Bind v-model to a local variable, but watch the prop value for changes and update local variable on prop change:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field v-model="localValue" @blur="compute" @keydown.enter="compute" />
</template>

<script>
import { create, all } from "mathjs";
const math = create(all);

export default {
  name: "NumericTextField",
  props: ["value"],
  data() {
    return {
      localValue: this.value
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value: function(newVal) {
      this.localValue = newVal;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    compute() {
      try {
        const result = math.evaluate(this.localValue);
        this.$emit("input", result);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Option 2 - use value as input value, but track v-text-field changes in a separate local variable. This way you don't need to use watch.

```
<template>
  <v-text-field :value="value" @blur="compute" @keydown.enter="compute" @input="onInput" />
</template>

<script>
import { create, all } from "mathjs";
const math = create(all);

export default {
  name: "NumericTextField",
  props: ["value"],
  data() {
    return {
      localValue: this.value
    };
  },
  methods: {
    compute() {
      try {
        const result = math.evaluate(this.localValue);
        this.$emit("input", result);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    },
    onInput(val) {
      this.localValue = val;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: We were thinking about the same solution in the same time :)  https://codesandbox.io/s/mathjs-vue-5e6m9?file=/src/NumericTextField.vue:0-624

Comment: I don't understand how using onInput here to assign this.localValue = val and then binding :value of the v-text-field to this.localValue is different from what I was doing before which was using v-model="this.localValue"... isn't that equivalent?

Comment: In Option 2 you are not binding :value to localValue, you are binding it to the prop `value`, i.e. `:value="value"` which is the parent's model value. But then you track changes made to v-text-field via onInput on a local variable, and only update the parent model (that is prop value) once you decide to emit the changes on blur or enter. Once emitted, the parent model value changes which changes this component value prop, and since the prop is bound to the v-text-field value it will be update.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because by using v-model, you change the localValue, which is not equal to this.value anymore. You should try to remove localValue completely, and use this.value instead.

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="value"
    @blur="compute"
    @keydown.enter="compute"
/>
```

```
compute () {
   try {
       const result = math.evaluate(this.value)
          this.$emit("input", result)
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        },
```

Comment: You have to bind `:value="value"` otherwise you'll end up with the component changing a prop value, which Vue will complain about.

Comment: If this.value is never changed unless it's the result of an emit input, then when would this.value ever equal "1+1" ? Here, you're using this.value as the input to evaluate, but this.value shouldn't be modified so it that's why I was using localValue to represent the string expression. If I use @beyers work around, the text doesn't reflow either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the text field directly to `value` prop using `value` attribute and remove the `localValue`

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    :value="value"
    @blur="compute"
    @keydown.enter="compute"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { create, all } from 'mathjs'
const math = create(all)

export default {
    name: "NumericTextField",
    props: ["value"],
    methods: {
        compute () {
            try {
                const result = math.evaluate(this.value)
                this.$emit("input", result)
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

if the above example doesn't work try out the following

```
<template>
  <v-text-field v-model="localValue" @blur="compute" @keydown.enter="compute"
 
  />
</template>

<script>
import { create, all } from "mathjs";
const math = create(all);

export default {
  name: "NumericTextField",
  props: ["value"],
  data() {
    return { localValue: "" };
  },
  watch: {
    value(v) {
      this.localValue = v;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    compute() {
 
      try {
        const result = math.evaluate(this.localValue);
        this.$emit("input", result);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/mathjs-vue-5e6m9)

Comment: I get an error about "avoid mutating prop directly" when I do this.

Comment: it should work according to [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

Comment: Try out to add `@input` with an empty handler

Comment: I'm seeing an error though when I use this exact code. Also, if you don't modify value letting the v-model of v-text-field change it to something like "1+1" like I was doing in localValue, how does this.value ever contain the value of some arbitrary path expression as a string? I thought I needed some local state for this. Perhaps I'm wrong but I don't see a workaround here in your answer yet.